# JQuery - data being set to buttons is the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, append

I have some JSON data. I am now trying to insert a table row. This row inserts fine.

The problem is that I want to attach data to each button.

Unfortunately the same data is being set to each one. So each button entered should have an data containing an ID from 1-infinity.

Here is the for loop in which I append all the items.

```
$("#market-table > tbody")
                        .append($('<tr class="row100 body">')
                            .append($('<td class="cell100 column1">')
                              .append(data.company.companyName)
                              .append('<span class='+changeClass+'>'+data.company.priceChange+'</span>')
                            )
                            .append($('<td class="cell100 column2">')
                              .append(data.company.marketType)
                            )
                            .append($('<td class="cell100 column3">')
                              .append(data.company.sharePrice)
                            )
                            .append($('<td class="cell100 column-actions">')
                             .append('<a href="#" class="market-action-button buy">Buy</a>')
                             )
                            .append($('<td class="cell100 column4">')
                              .append(data.company.sharesAvailable)
                            )
                        )
                        .find('.market-action-button').data("company-data", data);
                     }
```

Here is the click listener:

```
$(document).on('click','.market-action-button.buy',function() {
        marketData = ($(this).data("company-data"));
        console.log(marketData.company.id);
```

The same Id is printed each time.

Is it something to do with .find()?

Comment: ID? What ID? Can you be more precise? What is `.find('.market-action-button').data("company-data", data);` ? What's supposed to do? And what's inside `data` ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the company data like this:

```
 .find('.market-action-button').data("company-data", data);
```

add it when you generate the button item, you are overwriting it with the last call of the loop becouse you get all the buttons inside your table. Change:

```
.append('<a href="#" class="market-action-button buy">Buy</a>')
```

for

```
.append('<a href="#" class="market-action-button buy" data-company-data="'+data+'">Buy</a>')
```

Comment: Now if I fetch the data as I do with the onclick, the retuned data is [object object] and I cannot get any of the variables.